# Pass JSON string on click to Javascript tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've got a `while` loop which outputs a set of divs, a JSON string, and an `< a >` tag. When the user clicks the < a > tag for each individual output in the while loop, I would like the JSON string ($json) for that record to be passed into the JSON `var MapData = JSON STRING HERE` (without having to refresh the page). Below is an example of the pseudocode setup:

```
While statement
$json = json_encode($items)
< a tag onclick='pass $json' >

JavaScript tag
var MapData = GET $JSON < A tag > CLICK AND DECODE HERE
```

I think the best approach would be to use the onclick function or set the id on the a tag and have a Javascript/AJAX listener to update the JSON with $JSON but not sure how to do this. Note that I can't use the href to pass strings into the browser URL as I am using Bootstraps popup modal which requires href="#"

Comment: i think it's not a good idea to pass json strings, in an anchor, another solution could be, to set an id on the links and then, with an ajax call you'll get using a separate script the json string of the ID element.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a JavaScript function, and call it each time an  is clicked

```
< a tag onclick='myFunction($json)' >
```

then in your javascript code, define the function

```
function myFunction(json){
    /*do something*/
    // I believe you want to set a global variable MapData?
    // MapData = json;
}
```

Comment: var MapData is a variable in the JSON, I'm not sure whether function myFunction(json) would work...

Comment: $json encodes a JSON string using json_encode - I would like this string to be passed into var MapData in the JSON when the user clicks the a tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax, but if json is simple enough you could also use data element. Like this:

```
<a class="myjson" href="#" data-json="$json">My Json</a>
```

js

```
var MapData = MapData  || [];
$('.myjson').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = $(this).data('json');
    MapData.push(json);
    console.log(json);

 });
```

It all depends on your project and what's better fits your design...

Comment: I've tried modified code above and placing into a function, still no luck. I get map is undefined in the web console now

Comment: By the way, I've also got data-toggle and data-target already set on the < a > tag, I'm not sure whether that's causing any conflict

Comment: Here's the structure - JSON: var mapData = var MapData = MapData  || []; Just before the closing body tag, I've placed $(function(){$('.myjson').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = $(this).data('json');
    MapData.push(json);
    console.log(json);

 });});

Comment: why do you have  var mapData = var MapData = MapData || []?

Comment: It should only be var MapData = MapData || [];

Comment: I have var mapData = mapData  || []; it just got duplicated when moving here

Comment: javascript is case sensitive. So you wold have to make sure that it's either mapData or MapData and choose one

Comment: Yes - I have choosen mapData and replaced it throughout

Comment: Its strange, if i use MapData, the console says map is undefined and the AMCharts fails to load, but if i use mapData, I dont recieve any errors in the console but non of the data is displayed on the map (e.g. the JSON string is not pulling through)

Comment: Just inspected the HTML for data-json and as I'm using PHP to echo out the rows one by one, the quotations marks in the $json string are breaking the output of data-json, here is what it looks like when rendered code":"af","name":"af","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"al","name":"al","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"ao","name":"ao","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"ar","name":"ar","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"ch","name":"ch","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"uk","name":"uk","value":"2","color":"#fff"}]"="" data-json="[{"

Comment: If I'm guess right it should show data-json="[{"code":"AF","name":"AF","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"AL","name":"AL","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"AO","name":"AO","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"AR","name":"AR","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"CH","name":"CH","value":"1","color":"#fff"},{"code":"UK","name":"UK","value":"2","color":"#fff"}]" How can i achieve this in PHP - it's to do with all the double quotation marks but JSON requires this structure of json_encode

Comment: I've just escaped all the characters in a test data-json and it still doesn't load the data into var mapData and show on the map

Comment: Using your approach above with MapData and dummy data-json with escaped quotes, i get the following error in the console about 4 times TypeError: map is undefined

Comment: I've also tried var mapData = JSON.parse($('.myjson').attr('data-json')); but it says map is undefined

Comment: I've fixed the data-json - all characters are escaping. When I do alert(json); it doesn't display the array, but [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]